# How does the ZPL ^RS command works?

Tags: rfid, zpl, zpl-ii

According to the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) in the `^RS` command the second parameter sets the read/write position of the tag.
But in the description it says

> For the ZD500R only: F0 to Fxxx (where xxx is the label length in
> millimeters or 999, whichever is less)

But it also says

> The printer prints the first part of a label until it reaches the
> specified distance and then begins programming. After programming, the
> printer prints the remainder of the label.

So I'm confused, the value in mm has to be the length of my entire label or the distance between the beginning to RFID tag?

Comment: I would interpret that as the distance from the beginning.  It's *limited* to the length of the entire label; if you tried to specify a greater distance than that, the programming would never be triggered.

Comment: It is mm from the top of the label, so if you use ^RS,F10, it means 10 mm from the top, if you use the command without the F like ^RS,300 it means 300 dot from the top of the label, please keep in mind the printer resolution to measure the dots.